# Laravel-5.1 geonames, cloning repository using Composer

Tags: github, repository, composer-php, laravel-5.1, geonames

I want to use geonames for addresses on a website. I'm developing it using Laravel 5.1. I found this useful as a tutorial to get started: [Ipalaus Laravel 4.* for Geonames](https://github.com/ipalaus/geonames).

Because of its version incompatibility, I contacted a co-worker on the project who redirected me to use his repository: [My conversation with Javier Martinz on L-5.1 compatible update](https://github.com/ipalaus/geonames/pull/23). The simple solution was to add his repository which I did in `composer.json`. After running this I was expecting to have seen the repository cloned and have `artisan` command for geonames, to my surprise nothing of sort. I am using no version control like git, just storing locally.

How do I clone the repository? I have written him but no response for now. I suppose he's taken a break for the holidays.

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "@stable",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "illuminate/config": ">=5.1.0",
        "illuminate/console": ">=5.1.0",
        "illuminate/database": ">=5.1.0",
        "illuminate/filesystem": ">=5.1.0",
        "illuminate/support": ">=5.1.0",
        "symfony/process": "2.7.*",
        "guzzle/http": "^3.9",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/JavierMartinz/geonames"
        }
    ],    
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

This is the error I got when I added: `"ipalaus/geonames": "1.0.*"`

```
C:\Users\ken4ward\Documents\xampp\htdocs\tradersmart>composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.2.1)
  - Removing psr/http-message (1.0)
  - Removing guzzlehttp/promises (1.0.3)
  - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (2.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.1.1)
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.2.3)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing laravel/socialite (v2.0.14)
  - Installing laravel/socialite (v2.0.4)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader

C:\Users\ken4ward\Documents\xampp\htdocs\tradersmart>composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - ipalaus/geonames v1.0.0 requires illuminate/config 4.2.* -> no matching pa
ckage found.
    - ipalaus/geonames v1.0.1 requires illuminate/config 4.2.* -> no matching pa
ckage found.
    - ipalaus/geonames v1.0.2 requires illuminate/config 4.2.* -> no matching pa
ckage found.
    - ipalaus/geonames v1.0.1 requires illuminate/config 4.2.* -> no matching pa
ckage found.
    - ipalaus/geonames v1.0.0 requires illuminate/config 4.2.* -> no matching pa
ckage found.
    - Installation request for ipalaus/geonames 1.0.* -> satisfiable by ipalaus/
geonames[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further commo
n problems.
```

Comment: IMO there's not enough detail about what you did, or what did not happen, to answer this. Did you run `composer update` after updating the JSON file? What happened? Did a new dependency appear in your `vendors` folder? Does the Geonames dep need to be wired into Laravel in some fashion to appear in the Artisan command?

Comment: (Requests for urgency directed at volunteers on Stack Overflow or F/OSS projects on GitHub may be counterproductive, by the way - I would advise you to save those requests for when you're hiring someone! Furthermore, a pull request is not an appropriate forum for requesting support help - PRs are for a conversation relating to the proposed change.)

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://github.com/ipalaus/geonames)? It shows there how to update via Composer, and then how to set up the plugin using a provider registration. Just change your dependency as per Javier's note.

Comment: I did ran composer update after adding the repository as suggested by Javier Martinz, but nothing reflected in my vendor's folder as pertaining to geonames. Any suggestion? Thanks. Appreciate.

Comment: OK. Please add some detail to your question - would you edit in your `composer.json` in to start off with? Check it is valid JSON too please. Are you using version control for your own project e.g. Git? If so, clone your project in a new folder and run `composer install` from there - and examine the output. Is Geonames mentioned?

Comment: I think the json is valid because no error response when running update using composer. I'm running this locally, no version control system. could that be a problem?

Comment: Not using version control won't stop this working, but it's highly recommended. For now, delete your vendors folder and run the install command again.

Comment: Aha, [read this](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/use-a-github-branch-as-a-composer-dependency) - it looks like to use a Git repo as a dependency, a `require` entry is still required. Do you have one? I cannot see it in there.

Comment: In fact, when I added this: "ipalaus/geonames": "1.0.*", which is the only option I'm left with but  composer throw error because it not version L-5.1 compatible, only work for version 4.*. That was why I contacted Javier Martinz and, as you can see, he wrote that all i needed is is repository to be added, but that's not working.

Comment: Did you try the `dev` prefix, as per the last link I supplied?

Comment: OK. trying it out. Thanks. I'll give you the feedback in a minute.

Comment: I'm short of words to say thank you. Thanks a bunch!!!! It worked by using "ipalaus/geonames": "dev-master"

Comment: Would you add this as the answer so as to earn a score for this? Appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use ipalaus/geonames also, and it was not so nice. It did not function and the issue tickets I created months ago got no response. So I made [my own package](https://github.com/yurtesen/geonames) which imports much faster than ipalaus/geonames and more complete already. It took 15 hours to import the databases with ipalaus/geonames and it takes merely 30 minutes with my package.

Comment: Very easy to use. I appreciate your kindness.

Comment: Evren, is your change something that can be merged back into the original project, or is yours essentially a fork?

Comment: @halfer I wrote it from scratch so it can't be merged, it is not a fork.

I couldn't get ipalaus/geonames to function and author never responded to my issue report. Instead another person who had same problem responded (but since he switched to my geonames importer also) ->
https://github.com/ipalaus/geonames/issues/30
<- Also the owner of this question switched to my package as well. (as can be seen from his comment)

Comment: Alright, I guess if the original author isn't responding on GitHub, it may be abandoned. Good work `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Once I'd seen your `composer.json`, I wondered if this would just register the Git repo as an available source, but not specifically request it as a dependency. I therefore [ran this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=composer+git+dependency) and found [this blog article](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/use-a-github-branch-as-a-composer-dependency).

To summarise what that article says, it says that Git repo dependencies need to use the word `dev-` followed by the branch name you would like (this is usually `master`, but can vary). So, in your case, the solution in the `require` JSON array was:

```
"ipalaus/geonames": "dev-master"
```

From the conversation on the pull request, it seems that the change you wanted has now been merged down anyway. So you should now be able to follow these instructions and remove the Git repo:

> you should be able to required v2.0 for Laravel 5.1 composer require ~2.0 or v3.0 for Laravel 5.2 composer require ~3.0

If it is the case you can now use the Packagist version, do not feel that your time has been wasted - learning how to use Composer with special requirements (such as repo dependencies) is worthwhile indeed.